Field translations show up in UI, but not in nodes
I'm experiencing odd behaviors with content types built with Field module from Drupal core.
After this...
Translations are not imported
I got stuck in
Structure > Content types > [custom content type] > manage fields > [field] > Translate > [language]
modify the label, the help text and the Default value
drush cr
and still being unable to see the change in the node.
Closing the browser, changing the site language, repeating drush cr doesn't help.
Structure > Content types > [custom content type] > manage fields ...
translation are actually there.
If I drush config:export
I can see the translations get exported BUT they don't show up.
Visiting the node in various languages and running again drush cr doesn't help.
Translations show up in the UI but there seems no way to make them appear in the nodes.

Only one of the three items you mentioned as translated would show up in a node (on the front end), namely the label, if it's configured to show in managed fields, and/or if your theme displays it. All three would show up in the node form. I just tested and it works fine for me in a vanilla Drupal 11 (label is Body for English, Corps for French as expected), which may suggest that your theme isn't outputting the translated label properly. You can test this by temporarily switching to a core theme (e.g. Olivero), and viewing the nodes again

Thanks @Clive, I had no doubt the feature was working on a pristine Drupal installation considering such a bug wouldn't be unnoticed for so long.
Turns out that if any required field of an existing node hasn't been populated, translations somehow get imported in the UI but don't get displayed in the node.
That happened because some nodes were programmatically imported from a 15+ years old Drupal 6.
